# Need help solving this differential form exercise

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$ \int_\gamma \omega \space \space$ where $\omega(x, y) =x^3dx+ \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy \space \space $ and $\gamma[0, 2\pi] \to R^2 \setminus \{0, 0\} \space \space $ is given by $\gamma(t) = cos \space t, sin \space t) $

I first begin by calculating the following integrals:

$-\int{cos^3(t)sin(t)dt} = -\frac{cos^4(t)}{4} + c$

$ \int{cos(t)\frac{x}{x^2+sin^2(t)}dt} = arctan(\frac{sin(t)}{x})+c $

I'm not sure on what to do next, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given the parametrization, $\gamma(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$.

$$\frac{dx}{dt}= -\sin t, \frac{dy}{dt}=\cos t$$
Hence,
\begin{align*}
\int_\gamma x^3 \, dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \, dy &= \int_0^{2\pi} \cos^3 t(-\sin t) - \sin t(\cos t) \, dt \\
&= \left[\frac{\cos^4 t}{4}+\frac{\cos^2 t}{2}\right]_0^{2\pi}\\
&=0
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks! Is that it? Is the exercise over?

Comment: hmm... I thought so? I might have some careless mistake though. do check it.

Comment: Thank you very much.